# Augmented Dickey–Fuller test, Test Model

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I don't understand how we obtain the model that we test for a unit root in the ADF test. Let me explain better.

ADF test is used to test if a time series has a unit-root. We assume that the Data Generating Process of the time series is an AR(p).

$$Y_t = \rho_1\cdot Y_{t-1} + \rho_2\cdot Y_{t-2} + \rho_3\cdot Y_{t-3} +...+ \rho_p\cdot Y_{t-p} + \upsilon_t$$
$$ \upsilon_t \sim i.i.d.\text{N} \Big( 0, \sigma^{2}\Big)$$

In order to do so, ADF test the null hypothesis that   $\phi = 0 $ on the following model.
$$\Delta{Y_t} = \phi\cdot Y_{t-1}+ \gamma_1\cdot \Delta{Y_{t-1}} + \gamma_2\cdot \Delta{Y_{t-2}} + \gamma_3\cdot \Delta{Y_{t-3}} +...+ \gamma_{p-1}\cdot \Delta{Y_{t-p+1}} + \upsilon_t$$

My question is how did we derive the second model from the first one? Which math operations are required?

I tried to subtract $ Y_{t-1} $ from both side, some other manipulation and rearrangements but I didn't succeed. Lagged error terms always came up.

The book "Applied Time Series Econometrics" from Lütkepohl states that:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions? Am I misunderstanding or forgetting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly adapting my answer in [Why do we need a VECM specification if the I(1) processes are cointegrated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397644/why-do-we-need-a-vecm-specification-if-the-i1-processes-are-cointegrated/397665#397665), assume the following $AR(p)$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
y_t = \alpha + \phi_1{y_{t-1}} + \ldots + \phi_p{y_{t - p}} + \epsilon_t
\end{equation}
Using lag operators we can write this as
$$(1 - \phi_1{L^1} - \ldots - \phi_pL^p) \cdot y_t = \phi(L) y_t = \alpha + \epsilon_t$$
Define
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
\rho \equiv \phi_1 + \phi_2 + \ldots + \phi_p
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{3}
\zeta_s \equiv  - [\phi_{s + 1} + \phi_{s + 2} + \ldots + \phi_p]
\end{equation}
Rewrite $1 - \phi_1{L^1} - \ldots - \phi_pL^p$ by adding and immediately subtracting the coefficients of order $j+1$ to $p$ on the lag operator of order $j$. We get
$$
\begin{gathered}
  1 - [(\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \ldots + \phi_p) - (\phi_2 + \phi_3 + \ldots + \phi_p)]L \hfill \\
   - [(\phi_2 + \ldots + \phi_p) - (\phi_3 + \ldots + \phi_p)]L^2 \hfill \\
   - [{\phi_{p-1}} + \phi_p - \phi_p]L^{p-1} - \phi_pL^p \hfill \\
\end{gathered}
$$

Using \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} yields
$$1 - (\rho + \zeta_1)L - (\zeta_2 - \zeta_1)L^2 - \ldots - (\zeta_{p-1} - {\zeta_{p-2}})L^{p-1} - ( - \zeta_{p-1})L^p_ \cdot $$
Solving the terms in brackets gives
\begin{equation}\tag{4}\label{4}
1 - \rho L - \zeta_1L - \zeta_2L^2+\zeta_1L^2 - \ldots - \zeta_{p-1}L^{p-1} + {\zeta_{p-2}}L^{p-1} - ( - \zeta_{p-1})L^p
\end{equation}
The $\zeta_i$ appear both before the $i$th lag operator and, with reverse sign, before the $i+1$th lag operator. We can hence rewrite \eqref{4} as
$$1 - \rho L - (\zeta_1L + \zeta_2L^2 + \ldots + \zeta_{p-1}L^{p-1})(1-L)$$
Hence, we have rewritten \eqref{1} as
$$\left[ 1 - \rho L - \left( \zeta_1L + \zeta_2L^2 + \ldots + \zeta_{p-1}L^{p-1} \right)(1-L) \right]y_t = \alpha  + \epsilon_t$$
Multiplying out the square brackets, using $\Delta=1-L$, applying the lag operators and rearranging yields
$$y_t = \alpha + \rho y_{t-1} + \zeta_1\Delta y_{t-1} + \zeta_2\Delta y_{t-2} + \ldots + \zeta_{p-1}\Delta y_{t-p+1} + \epsilon_t$$
Subtract $y_{t-1}$ from either side to get
\begin{equation}\tag{5}\label{5}
\Delta y_t = \alpha  + (\rho - 1)y_{t-1} + \zeta_1\Delta y_{t-1} + \zeta_2\Delta y_{t-2} + \ldots + \zeta_{p-1}\Delta y_{t-p+1} + \epsilon_t
\end{equation}